# Since water can evaporate at any temperature above absolute 0, would the water cycle still be possible even without the Sun?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, water, earth

Since water can evaporate at any temperature (or even sublimate at less than 0°C, although at a very low rate: [Why does water not evaporate in below 0 degrees?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122829/why-does-water-not-evaporate-in-below-0-degrees/)), could there be a water cycle if there was no Sun? Would evaporation or sublimation of water occur with no external source of heat (even if extremely slowly),that then could fall as precipitations (in form of ice, snow, water...)?

Answer (score 4):

To have a water cycle you need water to evaporate and condense on the surface of the water at different rates. Without an outside source of energy it would reach equilibrium and there wouldn't be excess humidity condensing into clouds readily.

Comment: if there are cloud condensation nuclei in the air (or any particle that attracts water with force interactions) wouldn't that make clouds in those conditions? @shaihorowitz

Comment: Rain would be a flow of water going from the clouds to the water on the ground. How would the flow of water on the ground to the air happen to complete the cycle if there was an equal amount of water evaporating and condensing at the same time i.e. no net flow of water.

Comment: the thing is that there would be a situation of equilibroum or saturation, where no net flow of water would happen as you say, but the air would contain humidity. Then you could use hygroscopic particles or ions that would attract molecules of water and force them to condense at a higher rate. Then, if everything goes well, there would be a mild rain. Cloud seeding can be used in situations of equilibrium as you described (http://www.phys.ufl.edu/courses/met1010/chapter8-1.pdf) @shaihorowitz