# When we mix water with H$_2$SiF$_6$ and boil them, how much of the H$_2$SiF$_6$ evaporates?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, physical-chemistry, chemical-compounds

If water evaporates also at temperatures much lower then its boiling point, and so do, I believe, other liquids, how much H$_2$SiF$_6$  (boiling temp.  108 C) is to be found in the steam over boiling water? Can I calculate the ratio of any evaporated liquid in this steam based on its boiling point? And what is the meaning of the boiling point if any liquid evaporates in a varity of temperatures?

Comment: The compound hydrolyzes to hydrofluoric acid in aqueous solution.  Here is the vapor-liquid equilibrium behavior of aqueous solutions of HF at a total pressure of 1 atm:  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.851.2598&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic This feels smack in the middle of physical chemistry so it's not off-topic here. The last subquestion is very close to a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10470/how-does-water-evaporate-if-it-doesnt-boil though.

Comment: The general idea sounds like [distillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distillation) which is probably not easily covered in a Physics SE answer, however @ChesterMiller 's comment should be noted.  See also Wikipedia for this [Hexafluorosilicic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexafluorosilicic_acid).