# Why vapor pressure exist below saturation temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, phase-diagram

Say, there is water at $50^{\circ}\text{C}$ at 1 atm pressure on an open pot. Water boils at $100^{\circ}\text{C}$ at that pressure. So there should be no vapor at that condition as well as vapor pressure. There is vapor pressure but how?

Comment: google "why does water evaporate below boiling point", it's the first thing that shows up

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does water evaporate if it doesn't boil?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10470/)